# Setting controller to fill screen

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm developing for iPad and trying to make my view take up the full screen.  The problem is I have a status bar which fades away after a few seconds.  If I set the code of the view to be full screen then it is until the status bar goes away and I have 20px at the top of the screen.

I need the statusbar so I can't get rid of that.

Some sample code I've tried is:

```
- (void)setPhotoView
{

    [self.imageView setImage: _photo];
    self.imageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

}
```

As well as wantsFullScreenLayout in various places in my app.  I think the issue is that I can not get my view behind my app status bar.

edit:  (Some additional info)

Basically the UIImageView is the only thing in my UIView Controller.  I haven't done anything to alter the status bar programmatically.  There is really very little code as i've been trying to keep it basic until I get this working.

Comment: I guess I could also just wait to iOS 7 and it'll be a little easier.

Comment: Please show more code to answer: How is the status bar set set up? What view is it added to? When is setPhotoView called? To what view are you added the imageView? (I suspect the last one might be your problem)